# Lift object in place and follow mouse on other axis's

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to get a rigidbody to lift in place to a set height and then move on the other axis's with the mouse.

```
    private void levitateObject()
{
    Ray playerAim = playerCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));
    /*Finds the next position for the object held to move to, depending on the Camera's position
    ,direction, and distance the object is held between you two.*/
    Vector3 nextPos = playerCamera.transform.position + playerAim.direction * 5;
    //Takes the current position of the object held
    Vector3 currPos = levitatingObject.transform.position;

    levitatingObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = (nextPos - currPos)*10 ;

}
```

Comment: What's the question or problem?

Comment: At the moment is wants to stay a certain distance away from camera (5) but I want it to have the distance stay the same.